# Beta function for QED

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

What is the beta function for quantum electrodynamics?

I can't find it anywhere except on [Wikipedia article on beta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)#Quantum_electrodynamics), where the one-loop beta function is given by:
$$\beta(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha^2}{3\pi}$$
However, using the definition of the beta function
$$\beta(\alpha) = \frac{d\alpha}{d\ln(\mu)}$$
one gets:
$$\frac{d\alpha}{d\ln(\mu)} = \frac{\alpha^2}{3\pi}$$

After rearranging
$$3\pi\frac{d\alpha}{\alpha^2} = d\ln(\mu)$$
and integrating
$$-\frac{3\pi}{\alpha} = \ln(\mu) + C = \ln(\mu) - \ln(\mu_0) = \ln(\mu/\mu_0),$$
where $C = -\ln(\mu_0)$ is an integration constant, the result is:
$$\alpha(\mu) = -\frac{3\pi}{\ln(\mu/\mu_0)} = \frac{3\pi}{\ln(\mu_0/\mu)}$$
This gives non-negative monotonically increasing values for $\alpha$ for $\mu < \mu_0$ with a singularity at $\mu_0$ (I guess that would be the Landau pole).

However, for any finite non-zero value of $\mu_0$, $\alpha(0)$ seems to be
$$\alpha(0) = \lim_{\mu\to0^+}\frac{3\pi}{\ln(\mu_0/\mu)} = 
\lim_{\ln(\mu)\to-\infty}\frac{3\pi}{\ln(\mu_0)-\ln(\mu)} = 0,$$
while on the other hand $\alpha \approx 1/137$ should appear on low energies instead of zero.

Where is the catch?

Is there a term missing from the beta function above? For example, replacing $\alpha^2$ with $(\alpha - \alpha_0)^2$ should give the expected result, but it doesn't seem to be written like that anywhere. Is that replacement somehow silently implied nevertheless?

Answer (score 4):

First, a small correction to the algebra.

I follow you up to here.

\begin{equation}
3\pi \frac{{\rm d} \alpha}{\alpha^2} = d \ln \mu
\end{equation}

Then I think we need to proceed carefully. The way I would go would be to integrate from a reference scale $\mu_0$ to an energy scale $q$. Then
\begin{equation}
3\pi \int_{\mu_0}^q \frac{{\rm d} \alpha}{\alpha^2} =  \ln \frac{q}{\mu_0}
\end{equation}
Rearranging this yields
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\alpha(q)} - \frac{1}{\alpha(\mu_0)}  = -\frac{1}{3\pi} \ln \frac{q}{\mu_0}
\end{equation}

If you like, you can rearrange this to obtain
\begin{equation}
\alpha(q) = \frac{\alpha(\mu_0)}{1-\frac{1}{3\pi}\alpha(\mu_0) \ln \frac{q}{\mu_0}}
\end{equation}

In deriving this, we have implicitly assumed we can use a one loop approximation to the beta function. This requires that so-called "large-logs" do not appear. In practice, this means choosing a reference scale $\mu_0$ that is not too different from the energy scale of the processes you are interested in, $q$.

By taking $q \ll \mu_0$, you are breaking this assumption, and would need to resume the loarge logs in the beta function.

Or, you can choose a reference scale $\mu_0$ which is at the energies of the experiments you are interested in. At low energies, $\alpha(\mu_0)$ is small, and so $\alpha(q) \approx \alpha(\mu_0)$.

If that seems unsatisfying (what do I mean by large energies?), just note that $\alpha(q)$ will increase slightly at increasing $q$. If you keep matching $\mu_0$ to the energy scale $q$, eventually you will reach a point where the $\alpha(\mu_0)$ term in the denominator can't be ignored for an appreciable range of $q$.

Comment: Indeed, $\mu_0$ is often taken to be a fraction of  the electron mass, the smallest relevant mass for charged particles, and covers atomic physics, etc. Going to *much* larger distances to macroscopic phenomena  invalidates the simple formula, and IR accounting in QED is a recondite QFT problem.

Comment: The "correction to the algebra" is not really a correction but just a redefinition of integration constant(s) and the result also gives $\alpha(0)=0$.  The answer seems to suggest that the starting expression for beta function is not valid on lower energies. There should be an analytical expression that satisfyingly works on both lower and higher energies, without having to arbitrarily split the whole story into separate energy regimes.

Comment: @Danijel You misunderstand that this is a mere 1st-order perturbative approximation to your imagined analytical formula. It works within a limited domain, which covers practical cases of interest. Expecting global features of the RG from a first order approximation is misguided.

Comment: I agree with Cosmas's description. A lot of what makes QFT difficult is that we almost never have access to exact solutions, or *even the exact equations.* Much of the physics comes down to understanding when the approximations you are making are under control. In this case, one should take $\mu_0$ to be close to the energy scale of physics processes under study. (Of course, there are people who will run these equations over huge energy ranges without worrying about higher order corrections, but you should be skeptical of the information that can be robustly extracted from doing this)

Comment: @CosmasZachos Does this imply that, in order to get a better description of what happens at lower energies, one needs to include higher-loop contributions (which should manifest on _higher_ energies) or something else?

Comment: @Andrew I am aware that exact solutions are usually not available when one has only perturbative methods. But if there is a reasonable approximation at low energies and at higher energies (where running of the coupling starts to manifest), one would expect that one can get an analytical function that approximates both regimes reasonably well.

Comment: @Danijel something else. As I hinted, the infrared structure of QED (and QCD...) is a dark art. It is understood that from atomic to cosmological physics the coupling is stable/immutable,  but only nuts spend time on arguing the details...

Comment: @CosmasZachos So it is the case of "it works but only few people bother to understand why"? Where can I learn more about the infrared structure of QED for a better understanding of why the coupling does not go to zero at low energies?

Comment: I'm not expert. There are truckloads of papers if you google "infrared QED"... If *this* were the heart of your question, it is not quite apparent.